# How to reduce redundant MySQL function calls in a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, refactoring, sql-tuning

```sql
SELECT hour(datetime), COUNT(animal_id)
FROM animal_outs 
WHERE hour(datetime) > 8 AND hour(datetime) < 20
GROUP BY hour(datetime)
```

I am learning SQL. I am calling `hour(datetime)` four times in my query. I am curious 1) if this redundancy affects performance, and 2) how I can simplify this redundant code.

Comment: ,please check solution and let me know ..

Comment: I doubt that the multiplicity of the calls has much impact on performance. The impact comes in the query's inability to use an index, but I'm not sure that there's much you can do about that in this instance - except, as another respondent has suggested, create another column with just the indexed integer hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this affect performance?

Probably not in any meaningful way.  The performance of queries is usually dominated by the work done to retrieve and process data.  This is typically much more expensive than the overhead for built in functions (although there are some exceptions, such as regular expressions which can be rather expensive).

MySQL allows column aliases in the `GROUP BY`.  So a valid "simplification" is:

```
SELECT hour(datetime) as hh, COUNT(animal_id)
FROM animal_outs 
WHERE hour(datetime) > 8 AND hour(datetime) < 20
GROUP BY hh;
```

Two versions that are likely to make things worse might *look* simpler to you, but are not.  The first is to use `having`:

```
SELECT hour(datetime) as hh, COUNT(animal_id)
FROM animal_outs 
GROUP BY hh
HAVING hh > 8 AND hh < 20
```

Technically, this does what you want.  But because it filters *after* the aggregation, it is doing extra work on the `GROUP BY`.  That likely outweighs any savings on not calling `hour()`.

Another method is a subquery:

```
SELECT hh, COUNT(animal_id)
FROM (SELECT hour(datetime) as hh, animal_id
      FROM animal_outs 
     ) ao
WHERE hh > 8 AND hh < 20
GROUP BY hh;
```

In most databases, this would do what you want.  And it *might* in the most recent versions of MySQL.  However, MySQL has an irritating tendency to materialize (i.e. write to disk) subqueries in the `FROM` clause.  That adds extra overhead -- once again, probably more than the additional calls to `hour()`.

Note:  It is possible that `hour()` is a perniciously expensive function and you might find that either of the last two solutions are faster.  Also, you will probably only see an effect on performance if you data has at least a few thousand rows.  Trivially small tables (a few dozen or hundred rows) are usually processed quickly regardless of such concerns.

Answer (score 0):

- If hour column having integer value then try this one.We can remove only one time redundancy.

  `SELECT hour
      ,COUNT(animal_id)
  FROM animal_outs
  WHERE hour BETWEEN 8
          AND 20
  GROUP BY hour`
- If hour is in dateformat then try below code .

`SELECT DATEPART(HH,hour)
    ,COUNT(animal_id)
FROM animal_outs
WHERE DATEPART(HH,hour) BETWEEN 8
        AND 20
GROUP BY DATEPART(HH,hour)`